# undefined reference for the extern variable in C++ header

Tags: c++, arrays, header, extern

I have some code in C++:

```
// A.h
extern const char *names[3];

// B.cpp
#include "A.h"
const char *names[3] = {

   "Name1",
   "Name2"
   "Name3"
};

void getName()
{
    char *name;
    strncpy(name, names[0], 5);
};

// C.cpp
#include "A.h"
```

Then when I build it, it generate the following error:

undefined reference to `names'
What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: can you paste the build chain?

Comment: it builds ok for me. Btw, you are doing `strncpy` to unallocated buffer. It is wrong, you should allocate some buffer first.

Comment: Does your real code also have a semicolon too many in "B.cpp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in the example, you provided, I assume you do not just copy/paste the source. Like the semicolon in line `const char *names[3]; = {`, or the missing comma in the list of strings next to "Name2"

So about your question. You should not include the A.h in you B.cpp, I mean the line `#include "A.h"` should be removed. You include the header file, and use the extern keyword only where you will use the `*names` pointer in other cpp files.

Comment: yes, for this part "const char *names[3]; =", I changed it in the question part

Answer (score 0):

`B.cpp` shouldn't include `A.h` There's no need. The `extern` in `A.h` is a *declaration* that sets an expectation for the linker that a global variable can be found in another object file that's to be linked, but `B.cpp` is where the variable is *defined*.

Just make sure to link both `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` at link time.

Comment: Including the header ensures that any mismatch in the declarations gets reported at compile time, which seems useful.

Comment: Point taken. I've always avoided it for the reason above and because it seemed a bit misleading if you're declaring something `extern` and defining it in the same compilation unit, but I see where you're coming from.